# Embed an HTML iframe in iOS UITextView with swift

Tags: ios, swift, iframe, uitextview

I am looking to embed an HTML snippet with an `iframe` in it. I'm looking to play a video inside the `UITextView`.

Loading HTML on `UITextView` is not an issue here. When there is an `iframe` tag included in the snippet, it does not render as expected.

Using a `WKWebView` is not an option at this moment.

Any help would be a great help.

Comment: You are using a `UITextView`, because there are text? Or just because you have an iFrame? Because you are using `NSAttributedString` (which isn't mentioned), but NSAttributedString doesn't translate all HTML tags, only some. It's not a full HTML interpreter... That's why it doesn't work. So you want an iFrame parser/interpreter?

Comment: @Larme Yes. I guess that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Usually the best "interpreter" is a WebBrowser (it's its job), so `WKWebView` in our case... Or maybe look for an external lib if it exists, but I doubt it...

Comment: @Chrishan you can try this library and it might help.
https://github.com/tophat/RichTextView